# Kubernetes Ingress Port to Port route

Tags: web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I want to open my services outside. I decided to use ingress for this.
But directly over the IP without the hostname. For example, for an application running on port 9090, when I type IP:9090, it should go to the corresponding application. likewise 9091,8080,7070 etc.

I didn't choose to use NodePort, because it restricts between 30000 and 32767.Dec.

Ingress can I solve this problem with a general rule? or is Ingress a suitable choice for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to expose services directly via IP and port without using hostnames, you should use Kubernetes Services of type `LoadBalancer` instead of `Ingress`. `Ingress` is primarily designed for HTTP/HTTPS routing based on hostnames, whereas Services of type `LoadBalancer` allow you to expose services directly via an external IP address and port.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9090
      targetPort: 9090
    
  type: LoadBalancer
```